# code coverage none whereas percentage available

Tags: unit-test, visualforce-component, code-coverage

Actually, my code coverage for a class is shown up in my overall code coverage, but when i want to view the lines not covered in developer console, it show me none (see screenshot below)

[image]:

What options am i missing.

1. I already clear up my history, and launch my test class, the coverage has been recalculated
2. I do not have the "store only aggregate code coverage" checked

Comment: there are some issue related to developer console in Winter' 16. try to close and restart developer console again. it should fix your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be these known issues might help you to find an answer.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMoyAAE

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5JeAAK

Comment: Unfortunately there is no resolution for the time being, but the above links explain the issues been known, so it answer my question somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I got the following procedure from salesforce support when I opened a case on a similar issue with calculating code coverage:

1. Open Developer Console.
2. Click the panel "Query Editor" Tab at the bottom of the screen
3. Write the following Query in Query Editor: SELECT Id, NumLinesUncovered FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate
4. Check the checkbox "Use Tooling API" at the bottom of the screen.
5. Click "Execute".
6. Select all rows and delete them from "Query Results".
7. Make sure there are no records of ApexCodeCoverageAggregate
8. Deleted the old test execution histories
9. Compile all classes

At this point, try running your test class again and see if it behaves as expected.